# Django Admin Form, Set the default value of readonly Field (User Foreign Key Field )

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on a multi-vendor eCommerce site, in the model every item has a user, I want to save a User (read-only and item foreign key) while adding an item, I don't want to show the user field and if I use readonly_fields so my user will be null, how can I achieve that, Please help me

ADMIN.PY

```
class ItemAdd(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'price','minimum_order','status']
    list_display_links = ['name', 'price','minimum_order',]
    search_fields = ['name', 'description']
    ordering = ('-price',)
    list_filter = ['price', 'status', 'category']
    list_per_page = 25
    list_editable = ['status',]
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ItemAdd, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['user'].initial = request.user
        return form
    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to save, not display the user? In such cases, the solution is:

```
class ItemAdd(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'price','minimum_order','status']
    list_display_links = ['name', 'price','minimum_order',]
    search_fields = ['name', 'description']
    ordering = ('-price',)
    list_filter = ['price', 'status', 'category']
    list_per_page = 25
    list_editable = ['status',]
    
    # instead get_form method
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```